# How to back to different controller through params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: Restaurants and Meals

from `/restaurants/2` I have

```
<%= link_to 'New Meal', new_meal_path(restaurant_id: @restaurant.id) %>
```

My Meals controller has

```
@meal = Meal.new
@meal.restaurant_id = params[:restaurant_id]
```

I do this so I can auto populates my restaurant_id

I am having trouble redirecting back to `/restaurants/2` after I have created the meal.  Right now it redirects back to `meals/:id`.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Need more info. Please provide routing code and new and create actions from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller you can write:

```
redirect_to restaurant_path(params[:restaurant_id])
```